# how to get WordPress admin user table columns name in my plugin

Tags: users

I used this to get User list table columns Name.

[image: users list table]

```
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', array($this , 'new_modify_user_table'));

public function new_modify_user_table( $column ) {
    $column  // columns Name array , Looking for this array out side Users page
}
```

But manage_users_columns hook is not fired outside "/wp-admin/users.php", that mean It work When I am on page "/wp-admin/users.php" , but it did not Work On outside users page.

so,  How do I get User table Columns Name in My plugin? or on the outside "/wp-admin/users.php"

thankyou.

Comment: how do you want to use this columns if you are not as the "Users" page. edit your question to add more details.

Comment: Dear mmm, thank you for your question. I want to create a Plugin like "Admin Columns" (https://wordpress.org/plugins/codepress-admin-columns/) so i need to know the columns Name outside users.php.

Comment: For Dynamically add a column you have to know all the columns name, but it is Very Unusual to go to users.php to fire  manage_users_columns hook every time.

Comment: Columns can be added by other plugins.  They only get added when that filter runs (and when the other plugins decides - they may do it generally (all admin), or they may add the filter only if in users.php.)  Thus best you can do I think is assume default columns & that your plugin is in control of rest. You could apply_filters('manage_users_columns')  yourself to the default data, you might 'see' some other fields added.

Comment: this columns list in only generated in the file "wp-admin/users.php" then a idea to retrieve the list is to call this page, read the list in the filter `manage_users_columns` and store the list in cache.

Comment: Dear anmari, I followed your Suggestion but it didn't Work.  thank you for ur Suggestion.

Comment: Dear mmm. your suggestion is excellent and very similar to mine. do you have any Suggestion how may I call "wp-admin/users.php"  this page from My Plugin? by the way, I saved $column array to the options table. but I Didn't Know How To get   $column array globally

Comment: Yep ! solved it .   require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-users-list-table.php' );     $hmm =  new WP_Users_List_Table( array( 'screen' => 'users' ) );   $hmm->get_column_info()[0]

Answer (score 0):

Yep! solved it.

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-users-list-table.php' ); 
$hmm = new WP_Users_List_Table( array( 'screen' => 'users' ) ); 
$hmm->get_column_info()[0]
```

Comment: require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/screen.php' );  print_r( get_column_headers('users') ) ;  it will work too.